# different text direction for different lines for a poem text in flutter

Tags: flutter, text, direction

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iojSY.jpg) , [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZzTI.jpg)  I want to fetch text from Json file and show the text in different text direction for different lines

Trying to build with a listview.builder Is it possible

Comment: Please, share us you code example or an image of what you want to achieve to help you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Good, as it show up in the image the text seems to be always alternate, so you can apply a validation to alternate with the index. Try change the textDirection detecting if the index is odd or even.

```
ListView.builder(
  AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
    itemCount: this.yourValue.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index){

      return YourBuildList(this.yourValue[index],
              index.floor().isEven ? true : false); //here you can handle. If is even is TextAlign.start. If it is odd is TextAlign.end or vice versa
}),
```

As i said before, with a code example the anwers could be better, greetings.